# Changing Gateway and DNS addresses with batch file

Tags: windows, networking, dns, batch-file, gateway

I'm having a little crisis every time I have to change the gateway in order to access different sites from my workplace. It's time consuming and I'd be really glad if someone provides me with a script that would change the Default Gateway address as well as DNS address automatically by clicking a .bat file.

- There are two Default Gateway addresses : 10.10.23.236 & 10.10.23.1 (I need to switch between these two gateways constantly and it's really getting time consuming)
- DNS Server addresses are : Primary - 10.1.0.40, Alt - 10.1.0.50
                            Primary - 203.115.0.246, Alt - 203.115.0.247

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [netsh command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx):

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static IPadress SubnetMask GATEway 1

netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0 10.10.23.236 1
```

change the values to what you need.